# hacer un jquery en un php para que me realice una sentencia sin recargar pagina

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy creando un carrito de la compra pero me ha surgido un problema: Si tengo varios productos elegidos, luego, quiero que al dar al botón eliminar algún producto, pues se reste el precio del producto eliminado a la cantidad total, me han comentado que para no recargar debería hacerlo en query.

```phtml
<div class="producto">
    <center>
       <img src="./productos/<?php echo $datos[$i]['Imagen']; ?>"><br>
       <span><?php echo $datos[$i]['Nombre']; ?></span><br>
       <span>Precio: <?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio']; ?></span><br>
       <span>Cantidad:
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>"
data-precio="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio']; ?>"
           data-id="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Id']; ?>" class="cantidad">
       </span><br>
          <span class="subtotal">Subtotal:<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad'] * $datos[$i]['Precio']; ?></span><br>

<a href="#" class="eliminar" data-id="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Id'] ?>">Eliminar</a>
    </center>
       </div>
            <?php
                $total = ($datos[$i]['Cantidad'] * $datos[$i]['Precio']) + $total;
}
```

Comment: Hola Racxo, deberías intentarlo y presentarnos tu codigo con los problemas que te surjan o el error que te dé. Si no lo intentas, no puedes avanzar. Un saludo

Comment: Como jQuery te limitaron la respuesta, en lo particular  considero quisieron decirte Ajax (jQuery provee esto para su uso); coloca el código de lo que has realizado y donde estas detenido (y mensaje de error si lo hay) para poder guiar, si el Ajax se te complica recargar la página será tu opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que tienes que hacer es crear un clase que reciba ciertos parametros, o puedes hacer un intermediario para que los interprete y enrute. Paso siguiente crear un ajax que se ejecute en la accion que quieras

```
$("#miDOM").on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "miclase.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: val1: $("#primer_criterio"), val2: $("#segundo_criterio"), val3: $("#segundo_criterio"),
        success: function(resp){
            //aqui tratas tus datos que devolvio el php 
        }
    });
});

/*  PHP  */
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
    $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
    $val3 = $_POST['val3'];
    function miFuncion($val1,$val2,$val3){
        /*Aqui haces tus operaciones php*/
        /*Le haces un echo a los datos que quieres retornar al JS*/
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

espero te sirva